# want to bind string using comma separated using for loop

Tags: json

```
string json="[{\"ParentId\":\"a9764da3147845c184bd272cef6a5937\",\"Path\":\"/LMS/Cabinet/bdc2cd8e1da3451c84e332d1aa74f605\",\"CreatedBY\":\"admin\",\"IsActive\":\"Y\",\"CabinetName\":\"LMS\",\"FolderTag\":\"IT mobile computing,Comm Skills\",\"Name\":\"JAVA\",\"UpdatedBY\":\"\",\"Type\":\"Folder\",\"IsDelete\":\"N\",\"UpdatedON\":\"\",\"Id\":\"bdc2cd8e1da3451c84e332d1aa74f605\",\"CreatedON\":\"2015_09_08-11:19:50\",\"TemplateId\":\"dd42c8a71a954c1d948ef35492ee1242\" },{\"ParentId\":\"a9764da3147845c184bd272cef6a5937\",\"Path\":\"/LMS/Cabinet/3aae020c256f4dc1ab705af67bede2c7\",\"CreatedBY\":\"admin\",\"IsActive\":\"Y\",\"CabinetName\":\"LMS\",\"FolderTag\":\"IT mobile computing,Comm Skills\",\"Name\":\"Spring\",\"UpdatedBY\":\"\",\"Type\":\"Folder\",\"IsDelete\":\"N\",\"UpdatedON\":\"\",\"Id\":\"3aae020c256f4dc1ab705af67bede2c7\",\"CreatedON\":\"2015_09_04-16:58:05\",\"TemplateId\":\"dd42c8a71a954c1d948ef35492ee1242\"},{\"ParentId\":\"a9764da3147845c184bd272cef6a5937\",\"Path\":\"/LMS/Cabinet/c139b33a22a94a25bf624b94450aee3e\",\"CreatedBY\":\"admin\",\"IsActive\":\"Y\",\"CabinetName\":\"LMS\",\"FolderTag\":\"Social Skills\",\"Name\":\"SQL\",\"UpdatedBY\":\"\",\"Type\":\"Folder\",\"IsDelete\":\"N\",\"UpdatedON\":\"\",\"Id\":\"c139b33a22a94a25bf624b94450aee3e\",\"CreatedON\":\"2015_09_04-16:54:44\",\"TemplateId\":\"dd42c8a71a954c1d948ef35492ee1242\"}]";
```

This is my JSON string and I want to only "Name" field with comma separated into another variable.

For example, example:

```
string res={"JAVA","SPRING","SQL"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What language are you trying to do this in?  My first guess is javascript but i wasnt sure.

If its JavaScript, then you can get starten by turning the json string into a JavaScript object like this:

```
var jsonElements = JSON.parse (json);
```

From there its just looping and collecting the name property from each object.

---

#### Now we'll do this from C# instead

Ok, since you are doing the parsing from C# you would want this code instead:

```
string json = "[{\"ParentId\":\"a9764da3147845c184bd272cef6a5937\",\"Path\":\"/LMS/Cabinet/bdc2cd8e1da3451c84e332d1aa74f605\",\"CreatedBY\":\"admin\",\"IsActive\":\"Y\",\"CabinetName\":\"LMS\",\"FolderTag\":\"IT mobile computing,Comm Skills\",\"Name\":\"JAVA\",\"UpdatedBY\":\"\",\"Type\":\"Folder\",\"IsDelete\":\"N\",\"UpdatedON\":\"\",\"Id\":\"bdc2cd8e1da3451c84e332d1aa74f605\",\"CreatedON\":\"2015_09_08-11:19:50\",\"TemplateId\":\"dd42c8a71a954c1d948ef35492ee1242\" },{\"ParentId\":\"a9764da3147845c184bd272cef6a5937\",\"Path\":\"/LMS/Cabinet/3aae020c256f4dc1ab705af67bede2c7\",\"CreatedBY\":\"admin\",\"IsActive\":\"Y\",\"CabinetName\":\"LMS\",\"FolderTag\":\"IT mobile computing,Comm Skills\",\"Name\":\"Spring\",\"UpdatedBY\":\"\",\"Type\":\"Folder\",\"IsDelete\":\"N\",\"UpdatedON\":\"\",\"Id\":\"3aae020c256f4dc1ab705af67bede2c7\",\"CreatedON\":\"2015_09_04-16:58:05\",\"TemplateId\":\"dd42c8a71a954c1d948ef35492ee1242\"},{\"ParentId\":\"a9764da3147845c184bd272cef6a5937\",\"Path\":\"/LMS/Cabinet/c139b33a22a94a25bf624b94450aee3e\",\"CreatedBY\":\"admin\",\"IsActive\":\"Y\",\"CabinetName\":\"LMS\",\"FolderTag\":\"Social Skills\",\"Name\":\"SQL\",\"UpdatedBY\":\"\",\"Type\":\"Folder\",\"IsDelete\":\"N\",\"UpdatedON\":\"\",\"Id\":\"c139b33a22a94a25bf624b94450aee3e\",\"CreatedON\":\"2015_09_04-16:54:44\",\"TemplateId\":\"dd42c8a71a954c1d948ef35492ee1242\"}]";
dynamic jsonObj = (JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
List<string> names = new List<string>();

foreach (JObject item in jsonObj)
{
     names.Add(item["Name"].ToString());
}
```

Deserialize the string and cast it to a JArray.  Then foreach element in the array, we look at the Name property of the element.  I tested this code in visual studio and it appears to work.

Comment: m using vs2013 my foreach loop is also  dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
            
            List<JsonResult> res = new List<JsonResult>();
            foreach (var item in jsonObj)
            {
                res.Add(item.Name);
            }

Comment: i got error when m run application
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(WebApplication_Test.WebForm1.JsonResult)' has some invalid arguments

foreach (var item in jsonObj)
{
res.Add(item.Name);
}